# Archiving public Facebook posts from another person

Tags: facebook, archive.org

When trying to archive a facebook post from a public personality, `archive.org`, `archive.st` and `archive.ph` all cache the FB login page instead. Does someone know a web archiving service capable of saving facebook posts?

Comment: Related [Alternatives to archive.org](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/45379/14228)